# What all options do we have in Angular 5/6 to avoid polling for fetch realtime data form server

Tags: angular, rest, http

I am looking for any feasible solution for keeping our Angular UI updated, but at the same time we want to avoid polling (http calls towards backend in specified intervals).

I found different ways to do that, but still we are not clear.

References:

https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-polling/

http://resthooks.org/

Need some guidance in this topic.

Comment: Please publish your code, what did you try to achieve your result?

Comment: Maybe you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API websockets allows you to avoid polling and to communicate with your server in both ways

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, we are in initial phase of designing our new product. We are analyzing how to fetch/request updated data from backed over HTTP. In past we were doing that with polling, but now we are trying to find a better solution if exists.